# How can you make a site scroll down; as my site won't scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll, dimensions

There are two problems with my site. Firstly, there's the fact that it won't scroll down where there's excess space (See http://www.dragonclub.co.uk/kent.html). The second problem is that my site is unable to recognise its width so it's hard for me to put images or elements in as they don't adjust to site size (See http://www.dragonclub.co.uk/alnmouth.html).

Here's the content element:

```
#content {
 width: 100%;
 margin:0 auto;
 background:#ffffff;
 font-size:1.20em;  
 min-height:400px;
 padding: 0px;
 text-align: justify;
 line-height:1.5;
 }
```

Here's my site HTML:

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main-style.css" />
<head><link rel='shortcut icon' href='http://www.weebly.com/uploads/1/5/5/7/1557342/custom_themes/573159643243021653/files/Favicon.png?1394411094538'/>
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="YCJ0yvYRsfDH2J_NdKW-iYnJ5sqe4xPACCFAkOob_NI" />
<div style='display:none'>{title}</div>
</head><body><div id="menu"><nav>{menu}</nav>
<div id="header">{header}</div><div id="content">{content}</div>
<div id="footer-content" style="visibility:hidden">{footer}</div><div id="flexifooter">{flexifooter:content}</div></body>
</html>
```

It'd be great if you could help me, and other people struggling from the problems I am facing with site dimensions. Thank You!

Comment: We are **NOT** going to read through a literal wall of minified CSS, but you've obviously got `overflow:hidden` turned on, which utterly disables scrolling.

Comment: You are positioning you entire site in a ´position: fixed` on `#menu`

Comment: yups, move it out of the fixed menu div, and it's alright

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put all your content, footer etc. inside `<div id="menu">`
You need to move your content outside of this div, as it has position: fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your Site Please remove position:fixed from "#menu" element your site will start scroll. Please see below screenshot -

[image]